# Unable to see tkinter GUI in VS however the code works other editors

Tags: python, visual-studio, user-interface, tkinter

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import*
a= Tk()
a.title("test")
a mainloop
```

It doesn't give an error just says press any key to continue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You code should not run because the line `a mainloop` is invalid. It should be `a.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `a mainloop` part. It should be `a.mainloop()` instead.

Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
a = Tk()
a.title("test")
a.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!